# How to integrate bitbucket with intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket, development-environment, atlassian-sourcetree

Im trying to clone project from bitbucket in intellij, but I couldn’t establish connection between bitbucket and intellij?

How to generate rsa and dsa key in intellij to add in bitbucket?

Im not able to move forward from this first step, can somebody help me?

I know clone project in eclipse from bitbucket, but from intellij I couldn’t do that

Comment: Could you please share exact error message with us?
IntelliJ relies on command-line git (that you can run in Terminal for macOS and in cmd.exe for Windows) and the clone works fine in the command-line then IDE should be able to do it as well. 
* Where is the key stored?
* How is it called?
* Is there .ssh/config in place? Does it have an entry for IdentitiyFile?
* What is the format of the key? (rsa of the new openssh format, old rsa, edcsa, etc)

Comment: I’m not sure how to generate rsa and dsa key could you please help me on that

Comment: Please follow BitBucket guide on SSH:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/